# OS Ventura v 13.0 SMB share credentials messed up?

Tags: network, sharing, smb

I have a router which has a USB harddisk attached. This serves as a global storage and is accessible from smartphones and computers in our home network, either via LAN or Wifi.

As you might guess, the only computer not able to mount the SMB share as a registered user is the Macbook Air, running on Ventura 13.0 (further updates not available yet). On the other hand, when I allow guest access on the router, the Macbook will connect and works fine. To me it seems that not Samba is the problem but maybe messing up the credentials by the Mac's OS. Is there a solution?

Comment: 13.0 was superseded within a month of release, November 2022. The early releases were very buggy, which is likely the root of your issue. Current is 13.6. What happens when you try to update the OS? Have you ever run a beta OS on that Mac?